# Let's Encrypt certbot-auto fails because a Python / pip problem

Tags: python, lets-encrypt, certbot

Yesterday all was fine, but today, running the same command using certbot-auto to renew a certificate, I get this :

```
Upgrading certbot-auto 0.31.0 to 0.32.0...
Replacing certbot-auto...
Creating virtual environment...
Installing Python packages...    
/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/python: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmp.eUWQ3w7cFV/pipstrap.py", line 177, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/tmp/tmp.eUWQ3w7cFV/pipstrap.py", line 149, in main
        pip_version = StrictVersion(check_output([python, '-m', 'pip', '--version'])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I'm on Debian 7.9... someone with the same problem ?

Comment: [Certbot bugreport](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/6824) with some workarounds (including Felipes answer). Closed as wontfix since it only applies to End-of-Life systems.

Answer (score 23):

It's a problem with the newest versions (>= 0.32.x) over Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian 7.5.

Just clone a previous branch (I used 0.30.x):

```
git clone --branch 0.30.x https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
```

And use the option `--no-self-upgrade` when you run letsencrypt. In my case:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --no-self-upgrade --standalone -d mydomain.com
```

Don't forget to add `--no-self-upgrade` to your renew cron job.

Comment: This is the answer that I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that :-)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on a Debian Jessie box.
Are the letsencrypt guys aware of this problem?

Comment: @UwePost I guess so, this info is also available at their forums.

Comment: It worked amazingly ;-) When you stated Ubuntu 12.04; I said: "- This answer will fix the issue" ...Thanks

Comment: I get `Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found` T_T

Answer (score 2):

I made the following 2 changes in certbot-auto script and it works

**1st change**

```
pip_version = StrictVersion(check_output([python, '-m', 'pip', '--version'])
```

to

```
pip_version = StrictVersion(check_output(['pip', '--version'])
```

**2nd change**

```
command = [python, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--no-index', '--no-deps', '-U']
```

to

```
command = ['pip', 'install', '--no-index', '--no-deps', '-U']
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is happening in the process of upgrading your certbot package?

> ```
> No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
> ```

This *might* be a result of Python encountering a folder named `pip` in its include paths before finding the actual pip module. It's a bit tricky to debug this (you'd need to find out what Python's include paths are in this context, and then search these for the bad folder), but maybe you can fix the problem by removing and reinstalling the certbot-auto package.

(Your Debian version is pretty ancient, but the certbot version is not, and it's using virtualenv for its dependencies, so it's probably not that.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to restart apache about Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: Please explain your answer